# Specific order by IDs in a complex association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A candidate applies for a `job`. His application is a `matching`, which can be set to any `stage` in the interviewing process.

### Associations

```
# matching.rb
has_one :matching_stage
has_one :stage, through: :matching_stage
belongs_to everything else

# matching_stage.rb
belongs_to :matching
belongs_to :stage

# stage.rb
has_many :matchings, through: :matching_stage
has_many :matching_stages
```

### Question

I have an array: `@ordered_stage_ids = [2, 5, 6, 1, 17, 5]`.

I need to write a query that returns `@matchings` such that `@matching.matching_stage.stage_id` is ordered according to the `@ordered_stage_ids` array.

### Attempts

```
@matchings = @job.matchings.submitted.unrejected
  .includes(:matching_stage).order('matching_stage.stage_id', @ids)
```

This seems to work, but then I get the error:

```
@matchings.each do |m|

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "matching_stage"
LINE 1: ...) AND (matchings.employer_rejects = 'f') ORDER BY matching_s...
```

Comment: Your schema doesn't make sense.  Do you mean a `stage has_many matching through matching_stage`?

Comment: I'm still confused.  Your schema says `matching_stage` is a pair relating a matching and a stage.  There is no `order` there at all. What are you really asking?